# How to transverse the whole RGB cube for a 16.7 million color gradient

Tags: colors

Assume a color space defined by a 256*256*256 RGB cube. A 1d color gradient is formed by transversing the cube over some path between two points e.g. [1](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Color_Theory/Color_gradient#Linear_RGB_gradient_with_6_segments), [2](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=NRyGnjeNKJIC&pg=PA285&lpg=PA285&dq=1d%20color%20scale&source=bl&ots=XZU4i1C3Cu&sig=z7TM2Se-47H4R9v2N8fPKIDOCnA&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false). These are examples of a path that covers only part of the color space. I am interested in a 1d path to transverse all points in the cube continuously and form a 16.7 million color gradient. Are there any known formulations for this?

Edit: this is one possible answer: [Algorithm for generating a 3D Hilbert space-filling curve in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14519267/algorithm-for-generating-a-3d-hilbert-space-filling-curve-in-python)

Edit2: this shows some implementations: http://www.alanzucconi.com/2015/09/30/colour-sorting/

[6 segment gradient](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Color_Theory/Color_gradient#Linear_RGB_gradient_with_6_segments)

[color paths see fig 10.22](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=NRyGnjeNKJIC&pg=PA285&lpg=PA285&dq=1d%20color%20scale&source=bl&ots=XZU4i1C3Cu&sig=z7TM2Se-47H4R9v2N8fPKIDOCnA&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: might be a good fit also for http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You mean something like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_curve#/media/File:Hilbert3d-step3.png but then for a 256*256*256 cube? So what's the problem?